# Creating a push_back() function for MyVector

Tags: c++

I am trying to recreate a vector using my class MyVector.
I am stuck on creating the `function push_back()`

here is MyVector

```
template<class T>
class MyVector{
    private:
        T *v;
        int size;
        int max;

    public:
        MyVector();
        MyVector(int n);
        MyVector(int n, int k);
        MyVector(const MyVector &l);
        void grow();
        MyVector<T>& operator=(const MyVector &lhs);
        T &operator[](unsigned int i);
        void push_back(T t);
        int capacity();
        int length();
        void reserve (int n);
        void resize(int);
};
```

my `push_back()` function

```
template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::push_back(T t) {
    T *temp = v;
    v = new T[++size];
    temp[size] = t;

    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; ++i){
        v[i] = temp[i];
    }

    delete [] temp;
}
```

my driver program

```
int main() {
    MyVector<int> a(5, 1);
    a.push_back(9);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    } cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and my output

```
1 1 1 1 1 0
```

**Edit**

grow function()

```
template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::grow() { 
    MyVector *temp = v;

    v = new T[max * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i){
        v[i] = temp[i];
    }
    delete [] temp;
    max = max * 2;
}
```

Comment: Side note: `max`, `size` etc. should be `unsigned` (`size_t`).

Comment: For reference, you only need to `grow` when `size == max`, not on every push_back.

Comment: Your class needs a __destructor__ to release the allocated memory when a `MyVector` object is destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of off-by-one errors, as pointed out elsewhere, and this code also fails at exception safety.

---

### Annotated original code:

```
template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::push_back(T t) {
```

Taking T by value, instead of const reference and/or universal or rval reference, forces a copy here

```
    T *temp = v;
    v = new T[++size];
```

You reallocate your array on every push_back, even if size < max. So, what is max for?
Also, what happens if new throws bad_alloc here?

```
    temp[size] = t;
```

You copy the new value into the *old* array, which is too small for it. You put the larger array in `v`.
What happens if T's copy constructor throws an exception here? Your old array will be leaked, but you've already updated `size` and `v` to reflect the un-initialised last element.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; ++i){
        v[i] = temp[i];
    }
```

Remember, `temp` is the old array, so it has `size-1` elements. You're copying off the end.

```
    delete [] temp;
}
```

---

### Suggestions

- you already have a `reserve` method. Why not call that to guarantee enough space, and then just increment size and construct the new element?
- don't modify your structure until everything that might throw has succeeded

eg.

```
template <typename T>
void MyVector<T>::push_back(T const &t) {
  reserve(size+1); // if this doesn't throw, we now have enough room
  v[size] = t;     // if this doesn't throw, the hard work is done
  ++size;
}
```

now you just have to write `reserve` correctly ... this sample doesn't handle shrinking, but is at least exception safe

```
template <typename T>
void MyVector<T>::reserve(size_t newsize) {
  if (newsize > max) {
    size_t newmax = std::max(newsize, max*2);
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> newv(new T [newmax]);
    std::copy(v, v+size, newv.get());
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> oldv(v);
    v = newv.release();
    max = newmax;
  }
}
```

Comment: My reserve function is checks if newMax > max, if true then max = newMax.

Comment: Does it actually grow the vector to size max? `std::vector::reserve` does. Otherwise `max` doesn't give any useful information. Also note that the standard vector usually grows by a constant factor (eg, `max *= 2`) when it reallocates.

Comment: I have a grow function (see edit) however, when  I try to call v.grow() in my push_back() function I get an error  "error: request for member âgrowâ in â((MyVector<int>*)this)->MyVector<int>::vâ, which is of non-class type âint*â"

Comment: `grow` is a member function of your vector class, not of your `T *v` array. Also, since it doesn't take a size argument, it's not clear how you intend to use it.

Comment: what you suggested works fine. what would need to change in my reserve function though? if every time i call push_back it gives the vector one more space to add the new value shouldn't I never exceed the max?

Comment: Sure, but it's very slow, because you're doing an (expensive) reallocation and an O(n) copy on each push_back. That is, your push_back has linear complexity, which doesn't match the STL requirement. To get the required amortized constant complexity push_back, you have to grow by a constant factor every time you fill the current array.

Comment: @Useless: A single (style) comment, upon years I've come to use "guard style" conditions; in your case, the first line to `reserve` would thus become: `if (max >= newsize) { return; }` and the rest would be unindented. I have found that this type of condition increased readability in two ways: 1/ no need to wonder if something happens after the if-block, it's immediate 2/ it makes smaller blocks, so at the end of a block the conditions that triggered it are still fresh in the mind. You might want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

`++size` increments size, so `temp[size - 1]` becomes the last element in the array. The array has a size of just `size`, so your `for-loop` is wrong as well.
Your line:

```
temp[size] = t; //change to size - 1
for(int i = 0; i < size + 1; ++i) //change to i < size
```

So:

```
temp[size - 1] = t;
     ^^^^^^^^
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i){
                         ^^^
    v[i] = temp[i];
}
```

Comment: thanks! that worked. I see now after every ones answers where my problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors:

```
v = new T[++size];
    v[size-1] = t;// should be v and not temp

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i){// should run till size-2 since size-1 is already copied.
        v[i] = temp[i];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I changed what you said and the output stays the same 1 1 1 1 1 0

Answer (score 1):

Multiple errors, example if size was 10 before entering push_back:

```
template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::push_back(T t) {
    T *temp = v; // size = 10, temp is an array from 0 to 9
    v = new T[++size]; // size = 11, v is an array from 0 to 10
    temp[size] = t; // accessing temp[11] when there is 0-9 only, first error !

    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; ++i){ // looping from 0 to 11 when temp is 0-9 and v 0-10, second error !
        v[i] = temp[i];
    }

    delete [] temp;
}
```

Comment: Ahh,  I now see where my problem was. thank you for making it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum up, here's the final code that ended up working for me when I checked this answer out.  The variable names are slightly different.  I believe my ptr is the original poster's v.

```
template<typename T>
void MyVector<T>::push_back(const T & value){
    T *temp = ptr;
    ptr = new T[++s];
    ptr[s-1] = value;
    for (int i = 0; i < s - 1; ++i){
        ptr[i] = temp[i];
    }
    delete [] temp;
}
```